# For Xamarin new version release will local database file be overwritten?

Tags: xamarin.forms

I have a local database file being put in my assets and resources folder. The database file gets copied as a local database after I create all the tables. If I release a new version with a new updated database file in the assets & resources file will the database overwrite the previous one? If so what happens with the local database I have already created in the user's app?
Do I have to delete all the tables upon new version start up then recreate them with the new data? Or can they be merged?

I am coming to an end of coding my first app and I wanted to take this into consideration. Trying to future proof as much as possible.

Comment: it will only overwrite the local copy of the db if your code makes it overwrite the local copy.  That doesn't happen automatically

Comment: If I do overwrite the copy, can I delete the local database and recreate it or copy it as I did the first time?

Comment: You can do whatever you want.  It's just a file.